# In jQuery how to convert Objects to Float

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented the following function to compute the total value of a form:

```
$('tr').each(function(index, element) {
    if( ($(this).find('input.operation').val() == "add") || ($(this).find('select.operation').val()=="add")) {
         total = parseFloat($(this).find('input.subtotal').val( $('input:eq(1)',this).val() * $('input:eq(2)',this).val() ));
         console.log(subtotal);
    } else {
        console.log( $(this).find('input.subtotal').val( $('input:eq(1)',this).val() * $('input:eq(2)',this).val() ) );         
    }
});
```

But when I see the console log, it only says:

`[prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1].....`

instead of showing the actual value, so my question is how do I convert from Object to float?

parseFloat doesn't seem to be working (obviously because it only converts strings to float)

Comment: Did you try console.log on the variable you are using, i.e `total` and not `subtotal`, and right now it seems very global, and it contains a DOM element wrapped in jQuery, not a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the value it doesn't return the actual value, it returns the current jQuery object. Set a variable to the result of `.val()` and print that out instead:

```
var value = $(this).find('input.subtotal').val( $('input:eq(1)', this).val() * 
           $('input:eq(2)', this).val() ).val();

console.log( value );
```

Comment: Your variable is still set to the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  total = parseFloat($(this).find('input.subtotal').val( $('input:eq(1)',this).val() * $('input:eq(2)',this).val() ));
```

with

```
  total = parseFloat($('input:eq(1)',this).val())
        * parseFloat($('input:eq(2)',this).val());
  $(this).find('input.subtotal').val( total );
```

`$(...).val(...)` returns the object set which enables chaining, it doesn't return the value.

Comment: Why `parseFloat` when `*` would have clearly had to convert the strings returned by `.val()` to numbers?